# How to append context data for every log message in one class in NLog

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I want to append context data (like transaction id) to each log message created by one instance of a class. Currently I see only 2 ways of doing this:

- Formatting each log message with additional data (lots of additional code)
- Introducing private non-static log methods that will append necessary data (lots of overloads)

What are other options to accomplish this?

Comment: I have added a feature request for it, as I find it useful to add: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1615

Comment: I have edited the question and title to make it less broader, please remove the "on hold"

Answer (score 2):

Another option is adding the context data to NLog context class, like the [MDC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MDC-Layout-Renderer):

To Set:

```
MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("transactionId",1);
```

To Render:

```
${mdc:item=transactionId}
```

Other context classes are:

- [GDC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-Layout-Renderer): globally for all the threads
- [MDLC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/mdlc-Layout-Renderer): MDC with Async support
- [NDC](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ndc-Layout-Renderer): add context to a stack (push and pop)

There is no context class on Logger scope right now.